# Detect rectangular shapes from camera

Tags: c++, opencv, rectangles, rect

I need some feedback for a project I'm working on. Essentially I need to be able to track rectangular shapes from a video stream coming from a camera. I am using the OpenCV library for C++ to do so.
First of all I applied a colour detection (I need to track only 1 colour at a time). After that I applied the Canny edge detection in order to get the contours of the filtered image. At this point I should be able to determine whether there is a rectangle or not, it's position in the (x,y) plane (knowing the position of it's center or vertices won't be such a huge difference after all) and it's orientation with respect to such a plane.
All of this should be done in "real-time" in the sense that since the signal is coming from a camera I need to be able to track these feature of the shape shown in the stream.

This is a picture of the thresholded version of the input after the colour selection (left) and its contours, detected via Canny edge detection algorithm
[image]

This is the code in case anybody needs it:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>

#define HIGH_CANNY_THRESH  255
#define CANNY_KERNEL_SIZE  3
#define       FRAME_WIDTH  640
#define      FRAME_HEIGHT  480

#define    DISPLAY_IMAGES  true

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void createTrackbarsForHSVSel();
void morphOps(Mat &thresh);

int LOW_H  = 0;
int HIGH_H = 255;
int LOW_S  = 0;
int HIGH_S = 255;
int LOW_V  = 0;
int HIGH_V = 255;

int LOW_THRESHOLD  = 0;
int HIGH_THRESHOLD = 100;

int     CORNER_THRESH = 200;
int MAX_CORNER_THRESH = 255;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

   Mat src, hsvSpace, threshold, edges;

   vector<vector<Point> > contours;   // Vectors for the contours storage
   vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

   createTrackbarsForHSVSel();   // create trackbars for the HSV palette
   createTrackbar("Min Threshold", "Trackbars", &LOW_THRESHOLD , HIGH_THRESHOLD);
   createTrackbar("Max Threshold", "Trackbars", &HIGH_THRESHOLD, HIGH_THRESHOLD);

   VideoCapture capture;
   capture.open(0);

   printf("Starting to capture from camera0:\nisOpened = %d\n", capture.isOpened());

   capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,FRAME_WIDTH);
   capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,FRAME_HEIGHT);

   while(1)   // loop exectues as long as the user doesn't press ESC, q or Q
   {
      capture.read(src);   // read from camera
      cvtColor(src, hsvSpace, CV_BGR2HSV);   // RGB to HSV color space transformation
      // create a binary such that 1s are between Scalar(min_, min_, min_) and Scalar(max_, max_, max_)
      inRange(hsvSpace, Scalar(LOW_H, LOW_S, LOW_V), Scalar(HIGH_H, HIGH_S, HIGH_V), threshold);
      morphOps(threshold);   // morphological operations: they allow to close the 'hole' and delete the 'dots'

      // threshold now contains the binary that only displays one colour (if the trackbars are set correctly)

      // Apply Gaussian blurring and Canny edge algorithm for the edge detection
      GaussianBlur(threshold, threshold, Size(3,3), 0, 0);   // Kernel = 3x3, Sigmas are calculated automatically (see 'getGaussianKernel()')
      Canny(threshold, edges, LOW_THRESHOLD, HIGH_THRESHOLD);

      /*
         Algorithm that approximates the edges of the figure to a rectangle.
         After that it needs to be able to calculate the rectangle position and orientation
         (will something like RotatedRect be useful?)
      */

      #if DISPLAY_IMAGES == true
         // Show images
         imshow("Camera feed", src);
         imshow("Thresholded", threshold);
         imshow("Edges", edges);
      #endif

      if((char)waitKey(30) == 'q')
         break;
   }

   return 0;
}

void createTrackbarsForHSVSel()
{
   namedWindow("Trackbars", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

   createTrackbar("Low  hue", "Trackbars", &LOW_H , HIGH_H );
   createTrackbar("High hue", "Trackbars", &HIGH_H, HIGH_H );
   createTrackbar("Low  sat", "Trackbars", &LOW_S , HIGH_S );
   createTrackbar("High sat", "Trackbars", &HIGH_S, HIGH_S );
   createTrackbar("Low  val", "Trackbars", &LOW_V , HIGH_V );
   createTrackbar("High val", "Trackbars", &HIGH_V, HIGH_V );

   return;
}

void morphOps(Mat &thresh)
{
    // create structuring element that will be used to "dilate" and "erode" image.
    // the element chosen here is a 3px by 3px rectangle.
        // As a rule of thumb you want to dilate with larger element to make sure the object is nicely visible

    erode (thresh,thresh,getStructuringElement( MORPH_RECT, Size(3,3)));
        dilate(thresh,thresh,getStructuringElement( MORPH_RECT, Size(3,3)));

    dilate(thresh,thresh,getStructuringElement( MORPH_RECT, Size(3,3)));
    erode (thresh,thresh,getStructuringElement( MORPH_RECT, Size(3,3)));

    return ;    
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you considered Hough transformation? I used for detecting circle but it is applicable to every shape in theory

Comment: yes intersecting hough lines could result in yielding rectangles/squares

Comment: And where is the question exactly? Beacuse I'm NotSure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the rectangle is as well defined after thresholding as you've shown on the sample then this is a pretty basic task.

1. Use [findContours()](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html) to get the rectangle as a set of points.
2. Use [minAreaRect()](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) to draw the rectangle around contours (make sure the orientation stays the same.
3. Make sure to [find only rectangles](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d1/d32/tutorial_py_contour_properties.html) in case there's some noise in the future.
4. MinAreaRect already consists of all the information you need: `(x,y), (width, height), theta`. Remember to check out [this](https://namkeenman.wordpress.com/2015/12/18/open-cv-determine-angle-of-rotatedrect-minarearect/) before you go mad with the angle being weird.

Should work in real-time no problem. If you code something ineffectively and it doesn't, just do the processing every 2 or 3 frames.

Comment: After the Canny algorithm I used a findContours and after that I created a function that implements the minAreaRect algorithm. Works nice and kind pretty smoothly, now I just need to adjust some things to make it better. Thanks alot!

Comment: You're welcome. Consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem. Good luck!